# Signing every file created in a folder

Tags: java, hash, private-key, sha

I wrote a program in Java that creates an AVI file but i need help detecting every new AVI file that drops in the folder. For every new AVI file created it should be signed with a private key and an Hash should be created over it. I appreciate any assistance. Thanks in advance

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thanks for the feedback

Comment: This should help you : https://github.com/evrignaud/fim

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni thanks this was very helpful, what about if i want to sign the files with a private key